# solr parallel query search in single request using python

Tags: python-2.7, solr, sunburnt

How can I send multiple queries to solr server at a time using Python.

Here my code is:

```
import sunny

solr = sunny.Solr('http://localhost:8983/solr/gcss1/')

obj_query2=['Hdd failure','battery failure','smart error failure']

for i in obj_query2:
    a=solr.query({'q': i,'facet': 'on','facet.field': ['case_title','runtime']})
    print a
```

Here I am getting response one by one, but I need to hit all queries at a time to my solr server.

Comment: Do you want one result set with all the documents (containing either "hdd failure", "battery failure" or "smart error failure"), all do you want one result set for each term (one set containing documents matching "hdd failure", one containing documents matching "battery failure", etc.)?

Comment: I want one result set for each term (one set containing documents matching "hdd failure",one containing documents matching "smart error",etc )

Comment: with a single request you can't search solr with different q terms(or queries). you need to send multiple requests to solr with q parameter as one of ['Hdd failure','battery failure','smart error failure']

Comment: How can i send multiple requests to hit my  solr parallelly  with different "q" parameters .Let's say request 1 with  q:"hdd failure", request2 with  q:"smart error" ,request3 with q:"battery failure" etc.,